# Vlookup to return blank instead of 0 or #N/A

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am using vlookup to get data from a source but I want the result to be blank instead of 0 or N/A when there is no vlookup value. So far it gives me an error. My code:

```
ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:H,3,FALSE))+(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:H,3,FALSE)=""),"",VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:H,3,FALSE))"
```

**Edit** (Still it does not run)

```
ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastrow3).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,'[NOT OK.xlsx]Sheet1'!F:H,3,FALSE),"")"
```

Comment: Instead of using the `=IF(` formula, use `=IFERROR(`. =IFERROR(what_to_do_if_everything_goes_okay;"").

Comment: It still does not run !

Comment: Try no spaces between ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could emulate your example with a sample code, because you didn't provide a data to testing purposes.

The formula that worked:

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(B11;A1:A9;B1:B9);"")`

[image]
[image]